# Web Scraping using R Vest not showing the correct page after scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am learning web scraping in R , I used the following code for scraping some content from math.stackexchange but when I see the last output it is not showing the correct page also contents are different, can you please help on this , will be of great help.. thanks

```
library(rvest)

library(data.table)



link <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration"

url <- read_html(link) 

page <- url %>%   html_nodes(".question-hyperlink")  %>%  html_text()

page
questions_link <- url %>%   
  html_nodes("h3 a.question-hyperlink") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com", .)

get_answer = function(answer_link){
    answer_page <- read_html(answer_link)
  solution = answer_page %>% html_nodes(".accepted-answer") %>% html_text() 
  return(solution)
}

solution_accepted <- sapply(questions_link, FUN = get_answer)
```

Comment: Do you only need the links where the answers are accepted or need the content of the accepted answers?

Comment: @bdedu : In my final data, I need the questins in one column and only accepted answers in another column . Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Are you only interested in accepted solutions? If so, I would suggest a different approach.

Comment: @QHarr : Yes I only need the accepted solution , the final data will contain question in one column and accepted answer in other column.. where answers are not given it should show NA or blank.. please help me on this.. thanks

Comment: @QHarr that will also do, if I will get question and answer format table, in one column questions and other column only answers.. thanks once again

Comment: Given that answers have a special formatting how do you plan on representing this? The math symbols etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse) 

link <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration"
    
questions_link <- link %>%  
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("h3 a.question-hyperlink") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com", .)
```

The `get_answer` function gives the link of accepted answers.

```
get_answer = function(x){
  aa = x %>% read_html() %>%  html_elements('.accepted-answer') %>%
    html_attr("id") %>% str_extract("[0-9]+") 
 
  accepted_link = paste0('https://math.stackexchange.com/a/', aa)
  return(accepted_link)
}
```

Now using lapply to loop through the `question_link`,

```
accepted_link = lapply(questions_link, get_answer) %>% unlist() %>% str_replace_all('^https://math.stackexchange.com/a/$', 'NA')
```

Creating a dataframe with question and accepted answer links,

```
df = data.frame(question = questions_link, accepted = accepted_link)
```

Output

```
                                                                                                                            question
1     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328052/solving-complex-line-integrals-using-cauchys-integral-formula-for-derivatives
2                                         https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328035/compute-int-0-infty-frace-ax-fracbxx3-2dx
3       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328031/why-does-the-laplace-transform-shift-theorem-not-work-with-a-positive-shift
4             https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327779/explicit-elementary-primitive-integral-of-x-sqrtpx-and-galois-group-o
5                                        https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327770/how-resolve-int-infty-infty-frac-sin-xxidx
6                    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327737/show-that-in-lebesgue-theory-int-mathbbr2-f-sqrtx2y2-dxdy-2-pi
7  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327729/why-does-integral-equation-for-arcsec-have-absolute-value-in-its-argument-rather
8           https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327713/is-there-some-trick-intuitive-quick-way-to-solve-this-integral-equation
9                                          https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327711/prove-that-int-ab-fx-dx-int-a-cb-c-fxcdx
10                   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327691/is-there-any-trick-to-finding-int-0-pi-4-cos-6x-cos7x-cosnx-dx
11                                                       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327665/theorem-6-20-of-baby-rudin
12                https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327659/how-to-calculate-the-definite-integral-arcsinx-dsinx-x-from0-to-1
13                       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327658/evaluate-int-infty0-fracxx3-1-mathrmdx-by-using-complex-an
14                               https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327636/what-happens-when-we-change-the-order-of-integrals
15  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327592/is-it-possible-to-solve-n-body-problem-if-only-one-body-is-moving-and-all-other
                                   accepted
1                                        NA
2  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4328059
3                                        NA
4                                        NA
5  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327785
6                                        NA
7                                        NA
8                                        NA
9                                        NA
10 https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327755
11                                       NA
12                                       NA
13                                       NA
14                                       NA
15                                       NA
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response, however, I need the data frame in which first column represents question and the second column represents the accepted answer ( not only link ), can you please help me on this... thanks once again..

Comment: Do you need the text of the accepted answer?

Comment: yes, I need the questions and answer ( text only) not links.. thanks for your reply once again...